# Statics showing before all else

Tags: php

I'm having trouble calling a static method in the correct location. It always shows at the beginning of the html. As in such:

```
function topnav()
{
echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">".Site_Config::url()."</div><div class=\"col-md-3\">".Site_Config::title()."</div>";
}
```

Shows in the source of the page as:

`https://www.example.comExample Title<div class="col-md-3"></div><div class="col-md-3"></div>`

I'm not sure why this happens or if there is a way to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have mismatched html tags somewhere, which causes it to be out of place.

Comment: @andre3wap It is the first thing under `<body>` tag.

Comment: Show what's inside a `Site_Config::url()`. If there is `echo` — it's the reason.

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in a `<div class="row"> Static Method</div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you echoing the result of `url` function. Instead, return it.

```
class Site_Config {
    public static function url() { return 'some_url'; }
}
```

Comment: That was the issue. I tried print as well, same result as echo. Right before you posted this I tried return and it worked. Any documentation on why and when this will occur? Seems like echo usually works.

Comment: `echo` is a totally different operator. It outputs a string (writes it to `stdout`). `return` just returns a result of a function (or a method), so you can save it to a variable. When you do `"some" . "string" . some_func() . "more"` `some_func` has to return a string in order to concatenate it in a place. When you write `echo` instead of `return` you immediatly output a string and return `null`, which casts to empty string, and you get  `"some" . "string" . "" . "more"`.